# Grape Swagger describe JSON body

Tags: swagger, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm sending JSON request for most of the POST requests and I embed the JSON in the request body. How can I describe this using grape swagger ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding descriptions for params is easy (I assume that is what you mean by "How can I describe this using grape swagger ?"). Ivan shows you how to create the params blocks with a Hash or Array but to describe them with Grape Swagger you need to add a description parameter to the requires or optional in the params block.

```
class API::Users < Grape::API
  resource 'user' do
    desc 'Create a new user'
    params do 
      requires :user, type: Hash, desc: 'user object to create' do 
        requires :first_name, type: String, desc: 'First name of user'
        requires :last_name, type: String, desc: 'Last name of user'
      end
    end
    post do 
      # do work here
    end
  end
end
```

Both the desc before the endpoint and the desc keys in the hash sent to `requires` will be picked up by Grape Swagger and included in the automatic documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array or Hash to describe

```
params do
 optional :preferences, type: Array do
  requires :key
  requires :value
 end

 requires :name, type: Hash do
  requires :first_name
  requires :last_name
 end
end
```

Array when you need to save has_many objects.
Hash when you need to save just an object.

Ex:

```
params do
  requires :post, type: Hash do
    requires :title
    requires :description
    optional :images_attributes, type: Array
  end
end
```